# How to redirect to a template reloading the page content from a JSON request in Ember

Tags: json, ember.js, getjson, ember-router

I'd like to transition to a template but reloading the page content through a JSON request.

In other words, I load initially my index template through a `getJSON` request and then I go to another template where I modify some data. Later, I'd like to return to my initial template through an action handler with the the same `getJSON` request (it'll return another data different from the first one).

```js
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON("myurl");
    },
    actions: {
        goto: function(){
            $.getJSON("myurl");
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    }
});
```

I'm able to transition to my template and to do a new JSON request but the data I see is the initial one. This only works if I click `F5` because ember renders the template with the first `getJSON` call from model function.

EDIT:

I've reached a solution but I'd like to know if there is another better one without reloading the page.

```js
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON("myurl");
    },
    actions: {
        goto: function(){
            this.transitionTo('index').then(function(){location.reload(true)});
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Can you test this?

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON("myurl");
    },
    actions: {
        goto: function(){
            var newModel = $.getJSON("myurl"),
            that = this;
            newModel.then(function(model){
                that.transitionTo('index',model);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Error `Object has no method 'transitionTo'` which I'd solved with `that=this` and `that.transitionTo` getting another error... `More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route`.

Comment: I edited the answer with the that var, sorry. How is the response to $.getJSON("myurl");

Comment: This JSON response hasn't an associated model but it looks like `[{"attr1"{"id":"val1","attr2":"val2"},"attr3":val3}, ... {"attr1"{"id":"val1","attr2":"val2"},"attr3":val3}`.

Comment: Maybe you can take the controller and set the model manually, in the `then` function this.controllerFor('index').set('model',model)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? ;) By the way, I standardized my JSON response and now I'm not getting any error although my template still renders the initial data and not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe you can take the controller and set the model manually, in the then function this.controllerFor('index').set('model',model)

This is close to the right answer.

Ember will cancel a transition if the route is already rendered to the display, so your

```
this.transitionTo('index');
```

isn't actually firing.  That's where your problem is stemming from.  (It might be worthwhile to turn on ember debug for your app to output state transitions to the console, which will show that this is being terminated).

If you do want to modify the model while within a route, I would do so within the action handler of that route's controller directly:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        goto: function(){
            this.set('model', $.getJSON('myurl'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd already solved the problem but thank you for your answer!